# Conflicting UITapGestureRecognizer in UIView and for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UIView` in which I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Inside that view I also have a subview in which is basically some kind of a `UITableView`. The question is that why doesn't the `UITableView` recognizes the tap on a row, instead it goes to the tap gesture recognizer's handler all the time. Why is this, and how do I solve this? If I set the number of taps to 2, then it works fine. Any idea on how to solve this? Basically it doesn't call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` of your recognizer to `NO`. Otherwise, it "consumes" the touch for itself, and does not pass it on to the table view. That's why the selection event never happens.

Comment: [Setting this value to `NO` instructs the recognizer to deliver all touches to the underlying view, even when it has recognized the sequence.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: example code 'longPressGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;' (thank you dasblinkenlight)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight still not working for me,  i am not able to perform the touch events on my table view cell, i am not able to select the items from table view cell, I have used `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`but the items are not getting selected

Answer (score 27):

If you want **both** your `UITableView` **and** your `UITapGestureRecognizer` to receive touch events, then yes the `cancelsTouchesInView = NO` will work. If you want the tap gesture recognizer not to receive the touch events meant for the table view it is slightly less easy but very do-able.

Basically when you are creating your gesture recognizer you set self as its delegate. Then you implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method. A basic implementation might look like this.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:tableView];
    return ![tableView hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
}
```

Essentially this method (as implemented) asks the `tableView` if this touch's location falls within the `tableView`'s jurisdiction, and if it does, it will block the gesture recognizer from receiving the touch...allowing the `tableView` to receive the touch.

Comment: Couldn't we make this much simpler by changing line 3 and 4 to: `CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame; return !CGRectContainsPoint(frame, location);`?

Comment: @Aufwind Thanks for pointing out my overly complex calculation code. I must have rushed this answer too much. `CGRectContainsPoint()` is certainly a much better way to handle this calculation then I originally chose. However I have edited my answer to use `hitTest:withEvent:`. Which would be my preferred method for a few reasons. One of which would be an irregularly shaped view. If a view were presented as irregularly shaped (for example a circle that only handled touches in the circle area). This case would not be properly handled by the manual calculations I was performing. Thanks again.

Comment: It IS the correct answer. Should be the chosen one.

Comment: What if my view has no idea if one of its subviews has a table view?